# method returns before completionhandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I am developing a networkUtil for my project, I need a method that gets a url and returns the JSON received from that url using NSURLSessionDataTask to get a JSON from server. the method is the following:

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getJsonDataFromURL:(NSString *)urlString{
    __block NSDictionary* jsonResponse;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);
    }];

    [dataTask resume];

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

The problem is that the **completionHandler** inside my method and the **method itself** are run on **different threads** and in the last line the jsonResponse is always **nil**

How should I set **jsonResponse** with returned json from **urlString**?
What is the **best practice** for this issue?

Comment: It's because you're doing asynchrone calls. There are plenty of question about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block that is running in NSURLSession is running on different thread - your method doesn't wait block to finish.

You have two options here

**First one**. Send NSNotification

```
+ (void) getJsonDataFromURL:(NSString *)urlString{
       NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
       NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           NSDictionary* jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
           NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);

           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"JSONResponse" object:nil userInfo:@{@"response" : jsonResponse}];
       }];

       [dataTask resume];
}
```

**Second one**. Past completion block to this utility method

```
+ (void) getJsonDataFromURL:(NSString *)urlString
            completionBlock:(void(^)(NSDictionary* response))completion {
       NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
       NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           NSDictionary* jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
           NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);

           completion(jsonResponse);
       }];

       [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: What does this line do?        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"JSONResponse" object:nil userInfo:@{@"response" : jsonResponse}];
The problem is that I want to return jsonResponse, one option is your second option, I want to know if there is a way to return jsonResponse.

Comment: This line posts the notification to [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/).

Why do you want to `return` it? Use the second approach to perform whatever actions you need on getting response. You have asked about **best practices** - I gave it to you

Comment: the problem is that in another method I call getJsonDataFromURL and set its returned value to a variable and do some processes on it. `+ (NSNumber*) getServerVersion{
    NSDictionary* versionUpdateJson = [NetworkUtil getJsonDataFromURL:updateServerURL];
    
    if(versionUpdateJson){
        NSNumber* updateVersion = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[versionUpdateJson valueForKey:@"serverVersion"] floatValue]];
        
        return updateVersion;
    }else{
        return @-1;
    }
}
` ther again this problem raises

Comment: Here again goes the same approaches, I suggested. Same situation - same decision. But even better, I think, would be get rid of this `getServerVersion` method, and call `getJsonDataFromURL` directly. In case, of cause, it's suitable for your app organisation

Comment: So is it true that when using completionHandlers we can't return the values emerged inside the block and that the approach to use those values should be as your second one?

Comment: Yes, it is true. True, if blocks, where you emerge this value is running asynchronously to your method

Comment: There's no reason to have `jsonResponse` declared outside the block.

Comment: @newacct Absolutely. Edited

Answer (score 1):

Some people could say it is a horrible advice but you also can download your data synchronously. It should be done in a background queue. It is not a **best practice** but for some cases (like a command line utility, non-critical background queue) it is ok.

NSURLSession does not have synchronous download method but you can easily bypass it with semaphore:

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getJsonDataFromURL:(NSString *)urlString{
    __block NSDictionary* jsonResponse;

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0); // Line 1

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); // Line 2
    }];

    [dataTask resume];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // Line 3

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

NSURLSession has a [delegateQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSession/delegateQueue) property which is used for "delegate method calls and completion handlers related to the session". By default NSURLSession always creates a new delegateQueue during initialisation. But if you set a NSURLSession's delegation queue yourself make sure you do not call your method in the same queue since it will block it.

Comment: Yes, really horrible advice. Not an Objective-C way at all.

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr for guys like you I have added clarification. Also for specific cases like command line utilities it is a common approach.

Comment: a "guy like me" can not silently just move by your answer without commenting it =)

Comment: Problem with this approach is that you're not guaranteed, what queue will `dataTask` block will be dispatched to. Actually, it can be dispatched to the same serial queue, on which `getJsonDataFromURL` executes

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr It is not a problem. NSURLSession has a delegateQueue property (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSession/delegateQueue) which is used for "delegate method calls and completion handlers related to the session". By default NSURLSession ALWAYS creates a new delegateQueue during initialisation. If you set a delegation queue yourself than of course you should not block it.

Comment: yes, I missed that. Actually, I was to fast to judge, shame on me. I'm sorry. Couldn't you edit your answer, so I can up vote it? SO don't let me doing it without editing. Adding word, or punctuation will do :)

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously Method will return before Block is completed. Because that is main purpose of the block.

You needs to change something like this :

```
NSDictionary* jsonResponse;

+ (NSDictionary*) getJsonDataFromURL:(NSString *)urlString{

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        self.jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);

        [dataTask resume];

// ad observer here that call method to update your UI
    }];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior of "asynchronous calls". They shall not block the calling thread, but execute the passed block, when the call is done.

Simply add the code that has to be executed after getting the result in the block.

So instead of …

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getJsonDataFromURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
  __block NSDictionary* jsonResponse;
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
  NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:
  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) 
  {
    jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);
  }];

  [dataTask resume];

  return jsonResponse;
}
…
NSDictionary* jsonResponde = [self getJsonDataFromURL:url]; // BTW: get infringes the naming rules of Objective-C
// The code that has to be executed is here
```

… you do this:

```
+ (void) getJsonDataFromURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
  NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:
  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) 
  {
    NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);
    // Place the code to be executed here <-----
  }];

  [dataTask resume];
}
…
[self getJsonDataFromURL:url]; // BTW: get infringes the naming rules of Objective-C
// No code here any more
```

If the code executed by `-getJsonDataFromURL:` depends on the caller, simply pass it as an argument to the method and execute it at the specified location. If you need help for that, let me know. I will add the code for it.

Another solution is to use a semaphore and wait, until the completion handler is executed. But this will block the UI and is the not-intended way to do it.

Comment: You are sending class message to object `self` - error. And what you propose is violation of [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). What will you do, if you need this method in different classes in your program, and each is doing something different on getting response? V

Comment: 1. `self` is not necessarily a reference to an instance object. No error. 2. In this case I would reread my answer, esp.: "If the code executed by -getJsonDataFromURL: depends on the caller, simply pass it as an argument to the method and execute it at the specified location. If you need help for that, let me know. I will add the code for it."

Comment: So, you think that this method should only be called by Class object? It's error by meanings of this question's context. And by meanings of your answer - passing "code to execute" to `self`, that is Class-object? What for? It always will be the same.

Comment: actually I want to separate tasks and have this method just get the response json, so I can use this method later, so I can't put the code needed to be done after this method inside the block.

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr I do not know, why he does it. The method has been a class method in his Q. And in your A – oops. It was *not* his Q, whether this is correct and one cannot say it, because we do not have enough information to answer to this non-asked Q. Please reread the Q. But, of course, there are dozens of examples to send a message to `self` that is pointing to a class object. Did I say dozens? I wanted to say tons.

Comment: @Mahdi So simply pass the code to execute as an argument of type block and execute it inside the completion handler as said.

Comment: Then there's no reason to have `jsonResponse` declared outside the block.

Comment: @newacct That's correct, taken from the Q. Thank you!