# GCD NSURLSession completionHandler block return value null

Tags: ios, objective-c, task, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

I have a view with labels
these labels will have a new value when the viewdidload
inside the viewdidload there are calls for 2 methods.
The first one will call the a method from another class, that method will have an `NSURLSessionDataTask` which will have `completionHandler` block.
I want to set the new value for these labels from the session `NSHTTPURLResponse` as a dictionary object.
The Problem is, when the view did load the value for the labels is null.
I know it's because the view is calling a method before the first one is completed which is the block!

i don't know how to make the first method finish then calling the second one.

I tried to do this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ // 1
[AnotherClass method:argu anotherArgu:argue2]; // calling the method from the otherclass, this method have completionHandler block
_curentObj = [AnotherClass currentObje]; 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 2
[self setupUserLabel]; // 3 this method will set the new value for the label from _currentObj but it's null
});
});
```

I don't know how to make it finish the first call which is `[AnotherClass method:argu anotherArgu:argue2];` and then after finish and complete call the other one in the viewdidload.
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your thinking. Your results will likely not be available in viewDidLoad. Instead, you start the NSURLSessionDataTask, and in the completion handler, you get the results you want, format them as desired, and then do your UI changes in a call to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) **inside the completion block**.

The completion block gets called on a background thread, does the prep work, and then uses dispatch_async to invoke the code to install your new data into the UI on the main thread.

Comment: but the NSURLSessionDataTask is inside another class, I have a separated class for all the HTTPRequessts. I don't know how am I going to update the view from the otherclass, I know that I can call the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) inside the completion block but that if this method inside the view class but it's not ;/

Comment: So create a download method that takes a completion block, and call the completion block inside the URL task's completion block. Then call the download method and pass in a completion block that updates your label.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help!

Comment: I did exactly what you said, I found this answer in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/31178931/1322263 I choose the second option and inside the block I called the method that update the UI elements, but I have to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() to call the method thats update the UI elements, if I did not call the main queue the view will never be updated with the new data.

Comment: Correct. You must **always** make UI changes (and nearly all UIKit calls) on the main thread, or unexpected and/or bad things happen.